# Distribution (or Expectation) of Number of Non-Zero Coefficients in L1-Regularized Regression

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, regularization

Related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2458171/controlling-the-number-of-nonzero-components-in-the-lasso-solution), suppose we're performing L1-reguarlized linear regression. For a given regularization coefficient $\lambda$, what is the distribution over the number of non-zero parameters? If that question is too hard, can anything be said about the expected number of non-zero parameters?

To add some notation, let $A$ be a real $m \times n$ matrix. The L1-regularized optimization problem is
$$
x^* = \text{argmin}_{x \in \mathbb{R}^N} \quad \frac12 \| Ax - b \|_2^2 + \lambda \| x \|_1
$$

**Question:** Under what assumptions can we say something non-trivial for the following question: For a given $\lambda$, what is the expected number of non-zero elements of $x^*$, or more generally, what is the distribution of non-zero elements of $x^*$ ?

By nontrivial, I just mean I'm not interested in the case when $A=0$ and $b=0$.

Comment: Any correct answer to this question would be a function of the joint distribution of $A$ and $b.$  That's too general to be answerable here.  Could you expand your assumptions to focus the question?

Comment: No. I intentionally did not specify assumptions so that people could answer under any assumptions e.g.  "Well, under assumptions X, we can conclude Y." I am interested in all such answers, not merely answers under particular assumption(s). If you would like to help me rephrase the question to make this clear, I would welcome that edit.

Comment: This is too broad to be suitable for CV.

Comment: It's a perfectly reasonable question, clearly stated, and relevant to this forums purpose of "A Q&A site for people interested in statistics, machine learning, data analysis, data mining, and data visualization."  Why are you such a grump? Can you please reopen my question?

Comment: Let me also state that I cannot limit the question because I myself don't know what assumptions people have found useful/necessary to making statements. You're asking me to rephrase my question to implicitly contain its own answer.

Comment: Rather than trying to ask an (overly) general question, you can formulate the problem you actually face.  This site, like all other (technical) SE sites, focuses on real-world, practical problems that can be narrowly described.  It's not for general discussion or speculation.  Please read over our [help] for further information.

Comment: I just read the help center, specifically  What topics can I ask about here? and  What types of questions should I avoid asking?. The first says that questions about mathematical statistics are perfectly valid, and the second says that subjective questions should be avoided. My question seems perfectly valid. Can you clarify what rule you think my question is violating?

Comment: I also want to add that my question clearly satisfies your requirement that "This site, like all other (technical) SE sites, focuses on real-world, practical problems that can be narrowly described." My question is a real-world problem that I encountered in my research, and the problem is clearly and narrowly specified. I think you're being an overzealous guard dog.

Comment: If you want, I can add my research problem that motivated this question to the post, but it won't clarify the question in any way. I was trying to distill the question down to its essence so that others might recognize or answer it.

Comment: @RylanSchaeffer. If you feel strongly about this, you can raise this at [Cross Validated meta](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/) rather than in the comments here. It might be in your interests to state the reasons why you think your question should be re-opened there, and to refrain from using emotive, accusatory language. These issues can be resolved, in some form or another, without this kind of communicative noise; it also makes little strategic sense to antagonise, rather than persuade, those who influence whether a question gets re-opened or closed.